# Will replacing 'root' with 'self' in this code still yield a functioning binary search tree data structure?

Tags: python, tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

In an attempt to learn how to code a binary search tree in python, I came across this implementation -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/

They use 'root' in a lot of places that I'm used to seeing 'self'

Am I correct in assuming that replacing 'root' with 'self' at every location will still keep the data structure working properly?

Out of curiosity, why do they use 'root' instead of 'self'?

Comment: those functions are not class member functions, they're independent!

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed your assumption is right, that is if you are implementing these functions as methods to the class `Node`, but notice here how he defines them as functions outside of the class, where you can't use `self`

Comment: Oh I see, I did not notice that. Makes sense now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot replace `root` with `self`. First, notice the functions are outside of the class definition, so you cannot use `self`. Second of all, with every function call in these recursive sequences, `root` becomes `root.left` or `root.right` while self is constant within a class.